# Stopping time inequality

Tags: stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Let M be an a.s. continuous and increasing process.
Let $\sigma_c:=inf\{t\ge 0:M_t\ge c^2\} $.

I'm not able to figure it out why the following condition holds
 $$E[M_{\sigma_c}]\le E[c^2\land M_\infty] $$

any advise?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Brian I just observed that $ M_{\sigma_c}$ is = $c^2$ or equal to $M_\infty$ if it is never stopped. So it seems to me that the minimum of this two can't  be larger than $M_{\sigma_c$